# Excel conditional formatting multiple repeating rows

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, conditional-formatting

I'm using Excel 2010

I have a monthly menu. menu days are listed by row with 2 menu items list for each day.

### Col-C  Col-D

Day 1

- Cheesburger
- Hamburger

Day 2

- Taco
- Quesadilla

Day 3

- *Spaghetti*
- *Lasagna*

etc...

I want to highlight the items for a given day if the items on that day are NOT in alphabetical order.

I can create the conditional format for Day 1, but want to repeat the format for the rest of the items.  I've tried copying the format, but the absolute reference of day 1 causes all rows to be highlighted ONLY when day 1 is NOT alphabetical.  In the example above, only Day 3 should be *highlighted* since alphabetically "Lasagna" comes before "Spaghetti".

Comment: Your menu is making me hungry. :-)

Comment: any chance seeing what you already have in your conditional formula?

Comment: Why do you want to highlight items that aren't in alphabetical order?  Is this so that you can correct the order?  If so, why can't you just use custom sorting to resolve it for you?

Comment: @Iszi it might help to see an example of the custom sorting you mention in your comment

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't answer the question you've asked, but I think it addresses the need you seek to have filled.

First, I'll start with a spreadsheet that simply displays the data you've given.  Note that I've merged the cells for each day, for a simpler display.  I've also deliberately put the **Items** in non-alphabetical order, so you can better recognize the end result.

[image]

Next, we add a column that will copy the value in the **Day** column to an individual cell for each row in the **Item** column.  This column doesn't have to be where I've placed it, but it *must* be adjacent to the **Item** column.

[image]

Now, for the sorting.  For this to be done accurately, the following must be true:

- Each **Day** must have exactly the same number of rows as the others.
- All cells that will be sorted (better shown below) must be non-merged cells.

Now that you have all the data entered, select *only* columns B and C.  Then, on the Data tab, select Sort.  In the Sort dialog, make sure that "My data has headers" is selected.  Then, choose **DayValue** from the "Sort by" drop-down and leave the defaults ("Values" and "Smallest to Largest") in the other drop-downs.  Now, click "Add Level".  For this next level, you want to select **Item** as the Column, and leave the defaults of "Values" and "A to Z".  When done, your screen should look like this:

[image]

Now, just get rid of the extra column by selecting the column, right-clicking, and pick "Hide".  After that, all that's displayed is just the data you want shown, in the order you wanted it.

[image]